Is the acetylated form of L-carnitine stable at room temperature?
I just noticed that the Acetyl-Carnitine supplement that I used to ingest, tastes and smells differently.
Based on my research L-Carnitine seems to be stable over long periods of time, but does the same thing apply to the acetylated form of L-carnitine. I found this study that shows that once it's desolved in water it's not stable at neutral ph.
Is it stable over longer periods of time in the dark but at room temperature?
By "stable" I mean doesn't change it's chemical profile.

Stable in solution? Or stable dry?

Thx, Thorn. Meant stable dry.
